# Multimodule app finish previous Activity when navigate to another Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I have a project with different modules. I got `:ft_a` and `:ft_b` and they don't know about each other. There is a case where I want to go from `:ft_a` to `:ft_b` that I am using the Navigation component, so I use the [ActivityNavigator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ActivityNavigator) library.

When I navigate from A (in `:ft_a`) to B (in `:ft_b`), I want to finish Activity A. For this, I tried to use the `popBackStack()` function like the following:

```
ActivityNavigator(context).apply {
        this.navigate(
            this.createDestination()
                .setIntent(Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java)),
            null,
            null,
            null
        )
    }.popBackStack()
```

When I made this, Activity B started but it seems that the graph is not initialized or whatever, I just see the activity completely empty. If I remove the `popBackStack()`, then I am able to navigate from Activity A to Activity B with no problems, and Activity B is started correctly and I can see the Fragments that I declared in the navigation graph.

I don't know if this could be related to:

- Do I have my graphs declared incorrectly?
- Do I need to add some parameters to this navigation?

I also have tried to just use the "old" startActivity but it happens the same.

This is the `:ft_a` nav graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/auth_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.smb.ft_a.presentation.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="@string/login_fragment_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/goToSignUp"
            app:destination="@id/signUpFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/signUpFragment"
        android:name="com.smb.ft_a.presentation.signup.SignUpFragment"
        android:label="@string/signup_fragment_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_signup">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/goToLogin"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

And this is the `:ft_b` nav graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.smb.ft_b.presentation.firstView.FirstFragment"
        android:label="@string/first_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/toSecondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.smb.ft_b.presentation.secondView.SecondFragment"
        android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/toFirstFragment"
            app:destination="@+id/auth_nav_graph" />
        <argument
            android:name="isbn"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so my problem was that I was using nested graphs in the main graph, so my A Activity was my NavHost. That was causing that strange behavior. My **solution** was to delete the nested graphs from my main graph and just navigate using the ActivityNavigator to the Activity I want to navigate.

In this situation, then my Activity A is the NavHost for the navigation defined in `:ft_a`, and Activity B is the Navhost for my `:ft_b`.

PS: I created an independent module called navigator that is in charge of all the navigation and is all encapsulated in this module. I just declare an interface in my module and implemented it in the navigator module. There are a lot of post talking about this solution.